# DPST Switch and LEDs on High Power DC Lines

Tags: led, switches, dc, high-current

My goal is to wire up this LED indicator light so that when the DPST toggle switch is closed (ON), the LED will turn on. I have 30V LEDs that I can use that will use 20mA. However, this LED will be attached to high power DC lines. The load at the end of this schematic uses 30V and draws 30A.

Here are two of my ideas on how to wire this safely, which hopefully will prevent too much current flowing through the LED and causing damage.

[image]

For the top schematic, my belief is that this will work well when the switch is on. The LED will pull as much power as it needs to turn off.

For the bottom schematic, I think there may be an issue in that the LED will still be lit even though the switch is disconnected. I believe that the LED will pull from the PSU to complete the circuit and light up since it is bypassing the switch.

I appreciate any thoughts/feedback on these solutions. If there is a better way to wire this circuit or safety tips that I have not listed, I am open to proposed circuits.

Comment: Yes, the LED will always be lit in the bottom schematic since it is always connected to the 30 V supply. The top schematic is what you want, though it's hard to say if the LED will be safe -- are there possible transients which could kill the LED?

Comment: what is your specific question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first schematic will turn the LED on when the switch is closed, which it sounds like you want to do.  The second schematic will turn the LED on whenever power is connected which may also be useful depending on your system as a "power available" indicator or something.

As long as you properly size your resistor, there's no difference between connecting the LED to a line supplying a 30mA load or a 300A load.  Cheap nightlights will have a resistor connected to an LED that plugs right into an outlet.